# TypoScript - Render meta tag only if not allready set

Tags: typo3, meta-tags, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I use the following TypoScript to render the `og:image` meta tag

```
page.meta.og:image = TEXT
page.meta.og:image {
    typolink {
        parameter {
            cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
            cObject {
                file {
                    import.data = levelfield : -1 , og_image, slide
                    treatIdAsReference = 1
                    import.listNum = 0
                }
            }
        }

        returnLast = url
        forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
    }

    attribute = property
    if.isTrue.data = levelfield : -1 , og_image, slide
}
```

This works well and as expected.
But on some pages I set the `og:image` meta tag programmatically in a plugin.
That results in the problem that I have multiple `og:image` tags in my finished rendered page.

How can I extend the TypoScript above to only act if not already an `og:image` tag is set?

//edit
I am on typo3 v10.4

Comment: Please always mention your TYPO3 version.

Comment: Thanks for the hin, I added it to me post. I am on v10.4.*

Comment: As you have set meta-information with Typoscript, you will need to override meta-information instead of rendering another meta in your webpage. Some thing like given here: [Typoscript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51203820/5961782) or with creating custom Signal [Meta SEO Signal example](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/metaseo/stable/DeveloperManual/Index.html#signals)

Comment: are there a few pages or many? if it is a few pages you can use a condition around it:
[page["uid"] in [1,2,10]]

Comment: @Rustyjim no It could be many since its en element that the customer can use on a lot of sites.